# The 'this' keyword in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in JavaScript:

```
function main() {
   console.log(this);
}
```

How come this logs `Document`? Surely it should log `function main`?

If not, then how do I declare a variable within `main` to be accessed by the rest of the code as `main.varName`?

Thank you!

Comment: Canonical answer: `this` depends on **how** you call the function; it's dynamic, monkey-patchable.

Comment: @RahulTripathi oh yeah... sorry

Comment: "this" points to the global window object, or the newly created object if you call new main(); http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do something like this.

But then this would look something like a class object.

```
<script>

    function main() {
        this.testVar = "124";
    }

    var testMain = new main();

    alert(testMain.testVar);

</script>
```

The alternative is that you just create a normal global variable.

The way i am taking the code is a more class object way.

Hope i could help :)

Comment: No, what i did is not wrong.  You answer also lacks a reason.  Please make more filling comments, your comment as it is right now is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword references the context of the function, not the function itself.

When you call a function as a method of an object, then `this` references the object, otherwise the context is the global context (document).

Example:

```
var o = {
  name: 'myObject',
  fn: function(){ alert(this.name); }
};

o.fn(); // alerts "myObject"
```

As a function is also an object, you can add properties to it:

```
function main() {
}

main.varName = 42;

alert(main.varName); // shows "42"
```

However, this is not a regular use of functions and objects. Normally `main` would be a plain object rather than a function if you want to access `main.varName`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

```
var person = function(){
   return module = {
      setName: function(name){
         module.name=name;
      }
   }
};

var bill = person();
bill.setName('bill');
console.log(bill.name);
```